# Save the selected value in a select html

Tags: php, html

I have a small form with a select input.When I select a value and do the search in mysql the selected value is changed to the first.
How can I keep the value I have selected in the select?

```
<form method="post" action="Search.php">
  <div class="container">
<h5>Look at the selected server when searching!!</h5>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputState">Server</label>
      <select required name="server" id="server" class="form-control" >
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select a server</option>
        <option  value="server1">server 1</option>
        <option  value="server2">server 2</option>
        <option  value="server3">server 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

If I select server 2, I want server 2 to be selected for the next search.After performing a search, it returns to the first option of select a server.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you can select an option from this select input? Cause all your options are  disabled and can't be selected

Comment: Sorry, it was some tests that I was doing :P

Comment: How do you return to this page after performing a search? If you change page and then return to this one it's normal it gets back to the first value as is has the selected attribute, so you need to save somewhere what was the selected server and add a script to select to option that matches the previously selected server, or at least that's what I would do.